# Tools and supplies for roadside trailer bearing repair

Tags: bearing, trailer, boat

I've heard bearings are a common failure mode of trailers. What tools and supplies should I carry in my vehicle for doing an emergency bearing repair?

[image: boat trailer]

1. I have a bearing kit: [SKF 24 Trailer Seal & Bearing Kit (1-in Axle)](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/skf-24-trailer-seal-bearing-kit-1-in-axle-0130522p.0130522.html). Although I'm not sure how to determine if it's the right type/size or not.
2. Type of grease
3. Tools
4. Anything else

---

Wheel: [5.70-8 4-bolt](https://www.princessauto.com/en/570-8-4-bolt-trailer-tire-assembly/product/PA0008786063)

[image]

Comment: Something to think about is to worry about preventive maintenance more than worrying about having a breakdown on the road. If I were you, I'd put zerk caps on the hubs so you can push new grease into the hubs very easily. The number one killer of the bearings on these is because of water ingress. If you check the seals and keep it greased regularly, it becomes a non-issue and breakdowns due to the hubs will become non-existent. One of the issues is, if you suffer a hub breakdown, you'll do more damage before you notice it than what you can repair on the side of the road (most likely).