# Trailer axle dust caps — Sizing

Tags: bearing, trailer, grease

I want to order dust caps for my boat trailer that have grease fittings built in. Related: [Zerk caps for trailer bearings — Installation, tools, and supplies](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/93421/zerk-caps-for-trailer-bearings-installation-tools-and-supplies/93422?noredirect=1#comment159851_93422).

As @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 has pointed out, Princess Auto sells that kind of cap: [2 pk **2.44 in.** Axle Dust Caps with Grease Fitting](https://www.princessauto.com/en/2-pk-244-in-axle-dust-caps-with-grease-fitting/product/PA0009033457).

[image]

---

It might be hard to tell from these photos (due to a bad angle/distortion), but the OD of the cap is ~2 inches.

[image]

And the OD of the bearing enclosure is ~2.5 inches.

[image]

[image]

What size of bearing cap do I need? I can't find any 2-inch caps to buy in Canada, so that's why I'm wondering if I'm measuring the right thing or not.

---

For my notes, water drained out of the bearings when I removed the caps. So it's a good thing I'm doing this maintenance now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some 1.98-inch caps with grease fittings that are for sale in Canada.

https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B086V56DY4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

[image]

[image]

That's essentially the same as my OD cap measurement of 2 inches.

So I think that's my answer -- I need 1.98-inch caps for this trailer.